# Accessing node text using C# and Xelement (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the below XML and I load into a XElement in VB.NET and I can get the value of C easily with the below statement but when I try in C#, I get an error with the .Value .  How can I access the inner text of C with ease?  I can't seem to work out how to access it.

```
<A>
   <B>
       <C>Message</C>
   </B>
</A>
```

```
strMsg = oX.Elements("A").Elements("B").Elements("C").Value
```

Comment: "I get an error with the .Value" - *never* just say "I get an error". *Always* specify the exact error. Now, what do you want to happen if there are multiple elements? Because if you're only expecting a single element, you can just use `Element` instead of `Elements`, and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code works in VB due to an [extension member in `InternalXmlHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.internalxmlhelper.value).

The equivalent in C# would be:

```cs
string strMsg = oX.Elements("A").Elements("B").Elements("C")
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Or if you're expecting exactly one of each element in the tree, just use `Element` instead of `Elements`:

```cs
string strMsg = oX.Element("A").Element("B").Element("C").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `XDocument` class contains the information necessary for a valid a XML document, which includes an XML declaration. Working directly with `XElement` is a simpler programming model. You can access your XML value, add XML trees. The `Descendants()` method returns a collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, in document order.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\..\test.XML"); // Path Your Xml
var value=xdoc.Descendants("A").Descendants("B").Descendants("C").First().Value;
```